# Store completion handler and call success/error later

Tags: ios, swift, swift5, completionhandler

I have a protocol/function in my class which is below,

```
func getMovieList(completionHandler: @escaping (Result<[String], Error>) -> Void) { }
```

When the above method is called, I want to store the completion handler and call the success/error in the latter part.

I tried creating a typealias like below,

```
typealias AlbumListCompletionHandler = (((Result<[String], Error>)) -> Void)?
```

And in my class,

```
var completionHandlerObj: AlbumListCompletionHandler

func getMovieList(completionHandler: @escaping (Result<[String], Error>) -> Void) { 
    completionHandlerObj = completionHandler
    /...
    .../
}
```

But I wonder how do I call the success/error blocks in completionHandlerObj, kind of struck here. Can anyone help me with this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should work like this

```
completionHandlerObj(.success(["",""]))
completionHandlerObj(.failure(ErrorObject))
```

Comment: Darn it, I was trying the same. But my Xcode was crazy, now its working.

Comment: @Perseus I am glad it works now. Please accept the answer, maybe this helps others, too.